# How to encrypt Samba traffic?

Tags: samba, encryption

How would I create encrypt the traffic that Samba communicates between the server and the client? My settings without encryption look like this:

/etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server (Samba, Bananian)
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes
   follow symlinks = yes
   wide links = yes
   unix extensions = no

[myfiles]
   path = /mnt/drive01
   available = yes
   read only = no
   browsable = yes
   public = yes
   writable = yes
```

If I analyze an `SMB Write AndX Request` Packet in plain text. So I thought adding encryption to Samba would be adding `smb encrypt = mandatory` to the `[global]` section, but that results in the client (nemo) failing to connect to the Samba share `[myfiles]` with the message: `Error: Failed to mount Windows share: File exists. Please select another viewer and try again.`

What do I have to do to encrypt the Samba traffic between server and client? Is there any way to select the type of encryption (i.e. AES 256 with CBC ...)?